# Как спарсить значение тега с определенным атрибутом?

Tags: xpath, xslt

Как спарсить значение тега с определенным значением атрибута?
Ну типа

```
<xsl:value-of select="i"/> - это значение тега

<xsl:value-of select="i/@time"> - это значение атрибута
```

А как спарсить значение тега с определенным атрибутом?

Comment: Э-э! Зачем удалил ответ? Правильно же.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ответил сам себе, т.к. нашел ответ на свой вопрос, потом увидел, что ты ответил и решил, что лучше твой ответ отметить правильным. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте правильный xpath:

```
<xsl:value-of select="i[@time='value']" />
```

Условие выбора задаётся в квадратных скобках.

Здесь будет выбрано значение тега `i`, у которого есть атрибут `time` со значением `value`.

Comment: А как быть с if и when?
<xsl:value-of select="i[@time='0']"/> работает, а 
<xsl:when test="t[@time='0'] > 5"> и <xsl:if test="t[@time='0'] > 5"> нет

Comment: @DarthNyan - это должно работать. Нужно больше сведений о контексте. Возможно, стоит задать отдельный вопрос.